# Dynamically create a class in my project solution

Tags: c#, xml

i want to dynamically create a class in particular folder of my project

at the first project run time it create the class physically in some folder "Bridge" , Hereafter i would like to use this class directly and also want to view in the solution

is it possible ?

Suppose i have XML File

```
<Root>
  <ClassDynamic>
      <Field >
            <FieldName> ID </FieldName>
            <FieldType> int </FieldType>    
      </Field>
      <Field >
            <FieldName> Name</FieldName>
            <FieldType> string </FieldType>    
      </Field>
  </ClassDynamic>
</Root>
```

Create the physical class in  the folder

```
public class ClassDynamic
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it creates XSD schema file of your XML and then create C# class of the schema more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For creating the schema use Visual Studio click on XML tab and there is create schema, save this schema then customize this command and run it :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\XSD.exe" AppSettings.xsd /c /l:CS /n:"MyProgram.SomeNamespace.AppServices.Settings"
```

Comment: this works, but can you elaborate in more detail , like specify the source location and destination location

Comment: The cmd written above should be placed to same level as xsd, then .cs file will be genrated there, you can manipulate with xsd code to achieve your target structure , you can define there types of objects and also custom objects which are good for recursion etc. there is a lot of possibilities with creating XML and XSD also there are some powerfull tools and edtiors for creating best possible schema files

Comment: You can rewrite this command to some simply C# console program and make further file manipualiton after class is generated or something like that, you can also change the command to move file to different location etc , beasic C# or cmd knowledge should be enought